# How to solve the given task using BFS algorithm?

Tags: java

Is there any better or simpler solution for this task:

*"A matrix of dimensions MxN is given, filled with the numbers 0 and 1. The field on which the number 0 is written represents land, and the field on which it is written number 1 represents water. Write a function largestLake(int [] [] map) which calculates the size of the largest water surface in the matrix map. The size of a water surface is the number of fields of value 1 that that water surface contains. Two water cells are considered connected if they are adjacent horizontally, vertically or diagonally." ?*

Example:
Input:
4 5   //MxN
0 0 1 1 0
1 0 1 1 0
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1
Output:
6

I tried to find it with BFS algorithm, but it ended up with too many loops.
It says in the task that "The best solution has complexity O (M * N)."

I loaded matrix in main and here is my function:

```
        for(int i=0;i<mat.length;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<mat[0].length;j++) {
                if(!mat[i][j]) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        
        return false;
        
    }

    public static int jezero(int map[][]) { 
        Queue<Pozicija> red = new LinkedList<>();
        Queue<Integer> povrsina = new LinkedList<>();
        int suma = 0;
        int m=map.length;
        int n=map[0].length;
        
        boolean posecen[][] = new boolean[m][n];  //visited
        
        Pozicija start = null;
        
        while(visited(posecen)) {
            for(int i=0;i<map.length;i++) {
                for(int j=0;j<map[0].length;j++) {
                    posecen[i][j]=true;
                    if(map[i][j]==1  && posecen[i][j]==false) {
                        start = new Pozicija(i,j);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if(start==null)
                break;
            
            red.offer(start);
            
            int r[]= {1,-1,0,0,1,1,-1,-1};
            int k[]= {0,0,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1};
            
            suma=0;
            int dodatak=0;
            
            while(!red.isEmpty()) {
                Pozicija tren = red.poll();
                
                dodatak=0;
                posecen[tren.red][tren.kolona]=false;
                
                for(int i=0;i<8;i++) {
                    int sledR = tren.red + r[i];
                    int sledK = tren.kolona + k[i];
                    
                    if(sledR>=0 && sledR<m && sledK>=0 && sledK<n && posecen[sledR][sledK]==false) {
                        dodatak+=map[sledR][sledK];
                    }
                    
                }
                suma+=dodatak;
                
                if(dodatak==0) {
                    povrsina.offer(suma);
                    break;
                }   
                
            }
        
        }
        
        int max = povrsina.poll();
        for(int x:povrsina) {
            if(x>max) {
                max=x;
            }
        }
        
        return max;
        
    }
```

Comment: Ref: https://leetcode.com/problems/max-area-of-island/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using recursion.

```
    int[][] grid;
    boolean[][] seen;

    public int area(int r, int c) {
        if (r < 0 || r >= grid.length || c < 0 || c >= grid[0].length ||
                seen[r][c] || grid[r][c] == 0)
            return 0;
        seen[r][c] = true;
        return (1 + area(r+1, c) + area(r-1, c)
                  + area(r, c-1) + area(r, c+1));
    }

    public int maxAreaOfIsland(int[][] grid) {
        this.grid = grid;
        seen = new boolean[grid.length][grid[0].length];
        int ans = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < grid.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < grid[0].length; c++) {
                ans = Math.max(ans, area(r, c));
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

I hope this works for you, run it in the new class main.